# what does it means : cd [path to dir] 2>&1 1>/dev/null

Tags: unix

Please explain what does  `: cd [path to dir] 2>&1 1>/dev/null` in `UNIX BASH shell`

and also what is `difference` between `/dev/null 2>&1` and `2>&1 1>/dev/null`

Comment: I think you want to know the difference between `2>&1 1>/dev/null` and `1>/dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 4):

`1` is stdout (the standard output of a program), `2` is stderr (error output).
`2>&1` redirects all stderr output to stdout.
`1>/dev/null` redirects all stdout output to `/dev/null`, i.e. into nothingness.

So errors will be shown as output, and standard output will be suppressed.

Simple demo:

```
$ php -r 'fwrite(STDERR, "error"); echo "foo";' 2>&1 1>/dev/null
error
```

So, in your example, if changing to the directory succeeds, nothing much will happen, but if it fails, you'll see the error as standard output. Since AFAIK `cd` doesn't ever output anything on stdout (correct me if I'm wrong), redirecting stdout to `/dev/null` seems superfluous.

> ```
> /dev/null 2>&1
> ```

This by itself doesn't mean anything much. Again, stderr is redirected to stdout, but what `/dev/null` does here depends on what comes before it.

Comment: Given that `2>&1` **copies** `stdout` on `stderr` and `1>/dev/null` redirects `stdout` to nothingness, isn't it correct to say that this just discards standard output and moves standard error on standard output?

Comment: Indeed, my bad. It only suppresses stdout, not everything.

Comment: Why `php`?  This is easily done in the shell with: `sh -c 'echo error >&2; echo foo' 2>&1 > /dev/null`

Answer (score 1):

[RTFM](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html):

> ## 3.6.2 Redirecting Output
>
> Redirection of output causes the file whose name results from the expansion of word to be opened for writing on file descriptor n, or the standard output (file descriptor 1) if n is not specified. If the file does not exist it is created; if it does exist it is truncated to zero size.
>
> The general format for redirecting output is:
>
> [n]>[|]word
>
> If the redirection operator is ‘>’, and the noclobber option to the set builtin has been enabled, the redirection will fail if the file whose name results from the expansion of word exists and is a regular file. If the redirection operator is ‘>|’, or the redirection operator is ‘>’ and the noclobber option is not enabled, the redirection is attempted even if the file named by word exists.

---

> ## 3.6.8 Duplicating File Descriptors
>
> The redirection operator
>
> [n]<&word
>
> is used to duplicate input file descriptors. If word expands to one or more digits, the file descriptor denoted by n is made to be a copy of that file descriptor. If the digits in word do not specify a file descriptor open for input, a redirection error occurs. If word evaluates to ‘-’, file descriptor n is closed. If n is not specified, the standard input (file descriptor 0) is used.
>
> The operator
>
> [n]>&word
>
> is used similarly to duplicate output file descriptors. If n is not specified, the standard output (file descriptor 1) is used. If the digits in word do not specify a file descriptor open for output, a redirection error occurs. As a special case, if n is omitted, and word does not expand to one or more digits, the standard output and standard error are redirected as described previously.

---

> Note that the order of redirections is significant. For example, the command
>
> ls > dirlist 2>&1
>
> directs both standard output (file descriptor 1) and standard error (file descriptor 2) to the file dirlist, while the command
>
> ls 2>&1 > dirlist
>
> directs only the standard output to file dirlist, because the standard error was made a copy of the standard output before the standard output was redirected to dirlist.

---

- The file descriptor `0` is the standard input.
- The file descriptor `1` is the standard output.
- The file descriptor `2` is the standard error.
- `/dev/null` is the [null device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device).